# ui-sref="" Isnt redirecting me to a new page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm writting my html inside a javascript function but for some reason the `ui-sref` isn't working as it should. I'm creating an app with Ionic. Here is my code:

```js
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var resposta = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      var conteudo = "";
      for (i=1; i<=Object.keys(resposta).length; i++){
          conteudo += '<li class="item1" ui-sref="perfil" onclick="loadDoc()" >'+ resposta[i].nome + '<span class="item-note">'+ resposta[i].preco + 'e/dia</span><br><p class="local">'+ resposta[i].morada + '</p></li>';
    }
      document.getElementById("w1").innerHTML = conteudo;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://workup.pt/app.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

What can i do to solve this?

Comment: Did you add state handling to the `$stateProvider`? If so, would you mind posting that code here?

Comment: You mean $stateParams?

.controller('resultadosCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
loadDoc()
}])

Comment: Where is the $stateprovider

Comment: .state('resultados', {
    url: '/page3',
    templateUrl: 'templates/resultados.html',
    controller: 'resultadosCtrl'
  })

  .state('perfil', {
    url: '/page4',
    templateUrl: 'templates/perfil.html',
    controller: 'perfilCtrl'
  })

This? Sorry, im still learning angularjs and ionic, im new to it. The ui-sref worked fine when i wrote it in the html pages

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the DOM change by `$scope.apply()` so that AngularJS knows about the newly inserted HTML elements.

```
$scope.apply(function(conteudo){
   document.getElementById("w1").innerHTML = conteudo;
});
```

Comment: Do i have to put that in my controllers.js?

Comment: Because if i just add the $scope.apply in my js file it wont work cause scope its not defined

Comment: That snippet should replace the corresponding line in the `loadDoc` function you gave above.

Comment: You can make the scope available in the HTML by adding a method to your controller that returns the scope, e. g. `var self = this; self.getScope = function(){ return $scope;};` And then use it e. g. like `myController.getScope().apply( ... );`